# Check if a UIScrollView reached the top or bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Is there a way to know if a `UIScrollView` has reached the top or bottom? Possibly in the method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                  willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your class, and then add this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset == 0)
    {
        // then we are at the top
    }
    else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
    {
        // then we are at the end
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you are after! Else have a tinker by adding more conditions to the above code and NSLog the value of scrollOffset.

Comment: If you're in a `navigationController`, you might want to do something more like this: `scrollOffset <= (0 - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - 20)` and `(scrollOffset + scrollHeight) >= scrollContentSizeHeight`

Comment: Problem with that is the bounce...everything gets called twice once reaches top or bottom.  Is there a solution to that, besides turning off table or collection view bounce?

Comment: scrollOffset may be <0 if scrollview top constraint != 0

Answer (score 89):

Well, `contentInsets` are also involved, when you try to determine whether scrollView is at the top or at the bottom. You might also be interested in cases when your scrollView is *above* the top and *below* the bottom. 
Here is the code I use to find top and bottom positions:

Swift:

```
extension UIScrollView {

    var isAtTop: Bool {
        return contentOffset.y <= verticalOffsetForTop
    }

    var isAtBottom: Bool {
        return contentOffset.y >= verticalOffsetForBottom
    }

    var verticalOffsetForTop: CGFloat {
        let topInset = contentInset.top
        return -topInset
    }

    var verticalOffsetForBottom: CGFloat {
        let scrollViewHeight = bounds.height
        let scrollContentSizeHeight = contentSize.height
        let bottomInset = contentInset.bottom
        let scrollViewBottomOffset = scrollContentSizeHeight + bottomInset - scrollViewHeight
        return scrollViewBottomOffset
    }

}
```

Objective-C:

```
@implementation UIScrollView (Additions)

- (BOOL)isAtTop {
    return (self.contentOffset.y <= [self verticalOffsetForTop]);
}

- (BOOL)isAtBottom {
    return (self.contentOffset.y >= [self verticalOffsetForBottom]);
}

- (CGFloat)verticalOffsetForTop {
    CGFloat topInset = self.contentInset.top;
    return -topInset;
}

- (CGFloat)verticalOffsetForBottom {
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = self.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat scrollContentSizeHeight = self.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat bottomInset = self.contentInset.bottom;
    CGFloat scrollViewBottomOffset = scrollContentSizeHeight + bottomInset - scrollViewHeight;
    return scrollViewBottomOffset;
}


@end
```

Comment: Because of the vagaries of floating point math, I was getting a "verticalOffsetForBottom" of 1879.05xxx and my contentOffset.y was 1879 when at the bottom in Swift 3.  So I changed `return scrollViewBottomOffset` to `return scrollViewBottomOffset.rounded()`

Comment: As of iOS 11 `safeAreaInsets` also factor into it. `scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.height - scrollView.safeAreaInsets.bottom`

Comment: In iOS 11 and above you may need to use `adjustedContentInset` instead of `contentInset`.

Answer (score 42):

If you want the code in swift:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
        //reach bottom
    }

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0){
        //reach top
    }

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y < (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)){
        //not top and not bottom
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Simple and clean extension:

```
import UIKit

extension UIScrollView {

    var scrolledToTop: Bool {
        let topEdge = 0 - contentInset.top
        return contentOffset.y <= topEdge
    }

    var scrolledToBottom: Bool {
        let bottomEdge = contentSize.height + contentInset.bottom - bounds.height
        return contentOffset.y >= bottomEdge
    }

}
```

On GitHub:

https://github.com/salutis/swift-scroll-view-edges

Answer (score 5):

I figured out exactly how to do it:

```
CGFloat maxPosition = scrollView.contentInset.top + scrollView.contentSize.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom - scrollView.bounds.size.height;
CGFloat currentPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.topLayoutGuide.length;

if (currentPosition == maxPosition) {
  // you're at the bottom!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this(for Swift 3):

```
class MyClass: UIScrollViewDelegate {

   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
           //scrolled to top, do smth
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting code in your answer, it is helpful o explain how your code solves the OP's problem :)