# detect Swipe gesture in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer, touchesmoved

I am new to `iPhone` developer,

I made epub reader and loaded each page of epub in my `webview`

What i want to is, when user does `right swipe gesture` 2nd time then i want to navigate to new page, i do not want to do anything when user does `right swipe gesture` for first time.

`UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight`

Is there any method something like,

```
if(swipeRight.touch.count > 2)
{
  // do this
}
```

***Any help will be appriciated.***

**Thanks In Advance !**

**EDIT**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset == 0)
    {
        swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(swipeLeftAction:)];
        swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
        swipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired=2;
        swipeUp.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
        swipeUp.cancelsTouchesInView=YES;
        [_webview addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];  
    }
    else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
    {
        swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)];
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
        swipeDown.numberOfTouchesRequired=2;
        swipeDown.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
        swipeDown.cancelsTouchesInView=YES;
        [_webview addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];

    }
```

Comment: if webview in scrollview then yourcrollview.canCancelTouches = NO; and webView.exclusiveTouches = YES.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just attach UIGestureRecognizer subclass to that view and hold on for calls...

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* rightSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someAction)];
rightSwipeRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
rightSwipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
rightSwipeRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeRecognizer]; // add in your webviewrightSwipeRecognizer
```

Comment: I TRIED YOUR ANS BUT NOT WORKING, see my EDIT in question.

Comment: see my EDIT i am not getting gesture at all.

Comment: This piece of code is working for me when I add the gesture to self.view instead of webView. And gesture is being recognized over webview as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can tell the UIWebView's UIScrollView that its UIPanGestureRecognizer should only fire when your own UISwipeGestureRecognizer has failed.

This is how you do it:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
rightSwipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
leftSwipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeGesture];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipeGesture];

[_webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:rightSwipeGesture];
[_webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:leftSwipeGesture];
```

That should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try like below it will help you
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
    rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    rightRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
    [rightRecognizer release];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that swipe gestures offer support for the kind of behavior you are aiming at, but you can easily accomplish it by doing the following:

1. on the first swipe, set a flag and start a timer; for the rest do nothing;
2. on the second swipe,

   a. if the timer has fired (when firing, the timer reset the flag), do as per point 1.

   b. is the timer has not fired (the flag is still set), then do you action and cancel the timer.

You might event think of defining a subclass of UISwipeGestureRecognizer to encapsulate all this behavior.