# Scroll child scrollview only when parent scroll view reaches end

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a parent `UIScrollView` and a `UICollectionView` inside that `UIScrollView`.
I want that `UICollectionView` scroll begins only when the parent `UIScrollView` reaches end of its scrolling. Can any one please help me for the same.

Comment: put one codition in scrollview delagates method and check the your current scroll is end of your first scroll then disable it and make child scroll enable

Comment: you need off scrolling for collection view if Current contentOffSet of scrollview less than max off set of this scroll

Comment: Can you please show what all you may have tried in solving your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad, Disable Collectionview scroll.

```
self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Now, Use Delegate of scrollview to detect bottom of the scroll view and than enable CollectionView scroll.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
       self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Initially set the child scrollView `yourScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;` also add tags to your scrollViews. 1 for parent and 2 for child preferably.

Get to know if you are at the bottom of the ScrollView using this code

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView.tag==1)
    {
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset == 0)
    {
        // then we are at the top
    }
    else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
    {
        //Handle Code to activate the child scrollView.
        // then we are at the end
    }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding.

References [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706152/iphone-knowing-if-a-uiscrollview-reached-the-top-or-bottom)