# Scroll to bottom of WKWebView, macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView in macOS and was wondering: how do I programatically scroll to the bottom of the webpage?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: One of the properties of a WKWebview is a scrollView. With that in mind, this should get you squared away. https://stackoverflow.com/a/952768/4475605

Comment: @Andrew you can use my ans for wkwebview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871774/ios-wkwebview-detect-when-reaches-bottom/52885672#52885672

Comment: `WKWebView` doesn't have a `scrollView` property on macOS, only on iOS.